# API in Ruby in Rails like Twitter or Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication

I've read multiple blogposts and watched the railscasts episodes to APIs. But I still got one problem, I'd like to use the API in a way Facebook or twitter does. It should be possible to register an API client. The client should become an id and an secret (should be the same like username or password, right?).

Somehow I think devise could do everything for me but I'm not sure cause I'm kinda new to rails.

Is there a best practice or is the devise solution a good and common one?

Thank you guys! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booth that services use [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) so if you want to implement similar functionality you can use this technology also.

Comment: Thank you lukasz! The doorkeeper gem should help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper) gem. [Here](https://github.com/gottfrois/doorkeeper-provider-app) is a demo app using rails, devise and mongoid.